# Udev rule not executing script correctly

Tags: linux, udev, wacom

I have a udev rule 80-wacom.rules

```
    SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="add", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/wacom.sh"
```

My understanding is that it will run `wacom.sh` whenever any USB device is plugged in.

I verified that it was indeed triggering by logging the time of execution in a file.

```
    #!/bin/bash

    /usr/bin/date >> /tmp/udev.log;
    /usr/bin/xsetwacom set `/usr/bin/xsetwacom --list |grep -i stylus |awk {'print $6'}` MapToOutput HEAD-0;
    /usr/bin/xsetwacom set `/usr/bin/xsetwacom --list |grep -i eraser |awk {'print $6'}` MapToOutput HEAD-0
```

I have verified that it is writing the timestamp to the log file whenever a device is plugged in, but the crucial other two lines of code are not executing.

When I execute the script directly, the timestamp appears in the log file, and the other two lines of code execute as expected.

So the udev rule runs. The script runs. But the script as run by the udev rule does not perform as expected. I have tried adding a delay at the start of the script, but this does not resolve the issue.

I am at my wit's end. Any insight would be enormously appreciated.

Comment: Note that udev rules run in a restricted environment (`man 7 udev` for some details). In particular, there's no tty or X `DISPLAY` assigned to the script. `xsetwacom` looks a bit like it assumes a connection to an X server. The fundamental problem with that is that many X servers may be running at the same time, and your `udev` script has to figure out which one to use (if done properly, and not the hackish way). A clean solution is to run a demon as soon as the X server is started, and trigger this demon from the script. A less clean one is to fudge X server access from inside the script.

Comment: Another solution is to accomplish whatever you want to do in the configuration for the X wacom driver. `MapToOutput` looks like you want to assign the wacom input device to a particular session; this can also be accomplished in other ways (for example via `systemd`).

Comment: What I'm trying to do is constrain the stylus and eraser control to only move the cursor on a single display, as I have two. It was my understanding that the X window system combines all displays into a single X server.

Comment: If your two monitors are driven by the same graphics card, then you have a single X server ("display" in X terms) that probably uses a single framebuffer ("screen" in X terms) to drive both monitors. But that's by no means the only possible configuration. Please have a look at how to use `xorg.conf` for your wacom configuration (see e.g. last section [here](https://github.com/linuxwacom/xf86-input-wacom/wiki/Tablet-Configuration-1:-xsetwacom-and-xorg.conf)). I don't have a wacom tablet, so I never did that myself.

Comment: I have tried to make a systemd service that runs the script when triggered from the udev rule. The service was failing to start, now it's just not calling the script. How precisely can I use a systemd unit service to run a script when triggered by a udev rule?

I looked into xorg configuration for the wacom tablets. It seems MapToOutput isn't valid for configuration files, but is for `xsetwacom`.